# what's for the spring-cloud-turbine clusterNameExpression config mean?

Tags: spring-cloud, turbine

when i used the spring-cloud-turbine
i Configured the turbine

```
turbine:
  clusterNameExpression: new String("default")
  appConfig: crm,hystrix
```

i don't know what's the **clusterNameExpression** mean

when i started the `turbine` server, the log is

```
Just added and starting handler tuple: StreamingHandler_b9a27bea-5fda-4d0f-bfb9-3f2cd23f8066
2015-07-17 11:44:56.535  INFO 989 --- [nio-8555-exec-2] c.n.turbine.data.AggDataFromCluster      : Per handler dispacher started for: StreamingHandler_8d325fd3-bfa4-483f-809b-c7172483ad18
2015-07-17 11:44:56.535  INFO 989 --- [nio-8555-exec-1] c.n.turbine.data.AggDataFromCluster      : Per handler dispacher started for: StreamingHandler_b9a27bea-5fda-4d0f-bfb9-3f2cd23f8066
2015-07-17 11:44:56.536  INFO 989 --- [nio-8555-exec-1] c.n.t.monitor.cluster.ClusterMonitor     : All event handlers for cluster monitor: [StaticListener_For_Aggregator, StreamingHandler_b9a27bea-5fda-4d0f-bfb9-3f2cd23f8066, StreamingHandler_8d325fd3-bfa4-483f-809b-c7172483ad18]
2015-07-17 11:44:56.536  INFO 989 --- [nio-8555-exec-2] c.n.t.monitor.cluster.ClusterMonitor     : All event handlers for cluster monitor: [StaticListener_For_Aggregator, StreamingHandler_b9a27bea-5fda-4d0f-bfb9-3f2cd23f8066, StreamingHandler_8d325fd3-bfa4-483f-809b-c7172483ad18]
2015-07-17 11:44:56.536  INFO 989 --- [nio-8555-exec-1] c.n.t.monitor.cluster.ClusterMonitor     : Starting up the cluster monitor for default_agg
2015-07-17 11:44:56.536  INFO 989 --- [nio-8555-exec-2] c.n.t.monitor.cluster.ClusterMonitor     : Starting up the cluster monitor for default_agg
2015-07-17 11:44:59.157  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Fetching instance list for apps: [crm, hystrix]
2015-07-17 11:44:59.157  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Fetching instances for app: crm
2015-07-17 11:44:59.157  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Received instance list for app: crm, size=3
2015-07-17 11:44:59.208  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Fetching instances for app: hystrix
2015-07-17 11:44:59.208  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Received instance list for app: hystrix, size=2
2015-07-17 11:44:59.208  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: 5
2015-07-17 11:44:59.208  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Found hosts that have been previously terminated: 0
2015-07-17 11:44:59.208  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Hosts up:2, hosts down: 0
2015-07-17 11:44:59.220  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor   : Url for host: http://127.0.0.1:8111/hystrix.stream default
2015-07-17 11:44:59.220  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.handler.TurbineDataDispatcher      : 

Just added and starting handler tuple: default_agg_aggClusterEventHandler
2015-07-17 11:44:59.220  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.turbine.data.AggDataFromCluster      : Per handler dispacher started for: default_agg_aggClusterEventHandler
2015-07-17 11:44:59.221  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor   : Url for host: http://localhost:8010/hystrix.stream default
2015-07-17 11:45:59.157  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Fetching instance list for apps: [crm, hystrix]
2015-07-17 11:45:59.157  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Fetching instances for app: crm
2015-07-17 11:45:59.157  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Received instance list for app: crm, size=3
2015-07-17 11:45:59.157  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Fetching instances for app: hystrix
2015-07-17 11:45:59.157  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Received instance list for app: hystrix, size=2
2015-07-17 11:45:59.157  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: 5
2015-07-17 11:45:59.157  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Found hosts that have been previously terminated: 0
2015-07-17 11:45:59.158  INFO 989 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Hosts up:2, hosts down: 0
2015-07-17 11:46:02.629 ERROR 989 --- [nio-8555-exec-2] c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamingConnection       : Got exception when writing to response stream
```

i started **two same service with different ports**,but the `turbine` monitor **only hanldes the default one**;

**how can i configure the turbine to hanlde all the services?**.

i am a chinese, i'm sorry that my english is so poor

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation: http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.1/spring-cloud.html#_turbine

`clusterNameExpression` is a Spring Expression Language expression for where to get the name of the cluster from [InstanceInfo](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/master/eureka-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/appinfo/InstanceInfo.java).  The default is `appName`.  I wouldn't change `clusterNameExpression`.

You need to set `turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=CRM,HYSTRIX`

You need to add the cluster name from clusterConfig in the turbine url `/turbine.stream?cluster=<clustername>`.